# how to quickly switch to an already opened tab (buffer) in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vim, vimperator

I tend to open a lot of tabs during my everyday browsing and I've newly switched to **Vimperator**. I found that you can use `:buffer {number/keyword}` to navigate to an already opened tab.

But I think it has two drawbacks.

1. You have to enter `:buffer` as well as the buffer number or search keyword. That's a lot of typing.
2. What if you search by keyword and find a lot of matches, for example, several tabs have the **vim** keyword.

So my question is that: is `:buffer` the preferred way to quickly switch to an already opened tab? How to deal with the scenario of several similar tabs?

Comment: I don't know about Vimperator but vim is happy with just `:b <PartialMatch>`. fwiw, I have added following to my vimrc and find it quit handy: `nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply use `b` + keywords to filter the list and TAB to go through it.

I also switch to the previous visited tab with `C-6` for which I made another key:

```
" .vimperatorrc
map <A-v> <C-6>
```

now also alt-v.

And there's `1b` to go to the first tab (or any n tab) and `g$` to go to the last one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what is the meaning of this mapping `map <A-v> <C-6>` and what is the original keys to go to the previously visited tab?

Comment: `C-6` is the original key and means Control-6. I map Alt-v to the same (because it's handy on my keyboard). See `:helpall` and section 9.3. "changing tabs".